# Can functions with variable length arguments be compiled?

Tags: compile

Is there a way to `Compile` a function whose argument is a list of integers, the list having unknown length ? For example, `Max` ?

Comment: No. Use a integer vector argument instead. And there is no point in compiling `Max` because it is already compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of arguments must be known at compile-time. However, if you want to provide arguments of the same type, you can simply pass them as a list instead of single arguments

```
max = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}}, Max[list]]
max[{1, 2, 3}]
```